# Is there a way to page photos through the Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to download all my photos from Facebook and sort them by their upload date. Well, none of the 3rd party tools or Facebook used dates so I wrote my own app. It's a simple app that loops through the albums and gets the url, created_time, and Id of each photo, stores in in an array, then passes the array to a controller. The controller gets the picture data, turns it into an image then saves to to my file system.

I spent half a day learning the facebook api to learn that they limit the number of photos to 100 per call and I think 600 requests per 600 seconds.

I'm ok with the limitation of 600 requests per 600 seconds because I could just get the first 100, then the second, third, so on and so forth over a period of a few days. However, my major problem is knowing where to start and stop (programmatically).

This is what I have so far without every single function for brevity:

Javascript:

```
function getPhotos(callback) {
        var allPhotos = [];
        var accessToken = '';

        login(function (loginResponse) {
            accessToken = loginResponse.authResponse.accessToken || '';
            getAlbums(function (albumResponse) {
                var i, album, deferreds = {}, listOfDeferreds = [];
                for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //albumResponse.data.length
                    album = albumResponse.data[i];
                    deferreds[album.id] = $.Deferred();
                    listOfDeferreds.push(deferreds[album.id]);
                    getPhotosForAlbumId(album.id, function (albumId, albumPhotosResponse) {
                        var i, facebookPhoto;
                        for (i = 0; i < albumPhotosResponse.data.length; i++) {
                            facebookPhoto = albumPhotosResponse.data[i];
                            allPhotos.push({
                                'id': facebookPhoto.id,
                                'added': facebookPhoto.created_time,
                                'url': makeFacebookPhotoURL(facebookPhoto.id, accessToken)
                            });


                        }
                        deferreds[albumId].resolve();
                    });
                }
                $.when.apply($, listOfDeferreds).then(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(allPhotos);
                        downloadPhoto(allPhotos);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(allPhotos, error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

function downloadPhoto(allPhotos) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/download/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { allPhotos: allPhotos },
            success: function() {
                //alert('success');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }

function getPhotosForAlbumId(albumId, callback) {
        FB.api(
            '/' + albumId + '/photos',
            { fields: 'id,created_time' },
            function(albumPhotosResponse) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(albumId, albumPhotosResponse);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Download(List<Photo> allPhotos)
    {
        if (allPhotos != null)
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var photo in allPhotos)
            {
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(photo.url);

                    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
                    {
                        using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem))
                        {
                            // If you want it as Png
                            //yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png);

                            // If you want it as Jpeg
                            string x = @"C:\Users\xxxx\Pictures\" + photo.added.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_" + i + ".jpg";
                            yourImage.Save(x, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

Comment: You should use the paging URLs provided in the API response. Request the “previous” one, and do so until you get no more data.

Comment: I got paging data from the album response but not for the photos in an album.

Comment: Check when you no longer get the 'next' pagination link, or the data array is empty.